# Webpack.mix, vue.js - compilation parameters

Tags: webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a webpack.mix.js file (laravel mix) that I use for compiling javascript and scss. It works well, but I need a dynamic parameter. Right now I have:

```
//let result = 'https://www.web1.com/';
let result = 'https://stage.web1.com/';

    output: {
        publicPath: result,
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
```

This works fine, but I have to change the parameter manually when I switch between the localhost/stage/live version.

What I would like to do is to run:

```
npm run local
npm run stage
npm run live
```

and the path parameter would be inserted automatically.

Right now, the npm run prod executes this:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

How can I insert a parameter into this last line?

Comment: Just set the `NODE_ENV` accordingly, then you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks. Doesn't laravel mix use the ENV somewhere? I mean isn't "production" or "development" important for some actions? Can I freely replace it with "stage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Ohgodwhy's comment:

```
let result = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" ?
  'https://www.web1.com/' :
  'https://stage.web1.com/'
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks I am testing that. It seems working. I am just concerned whether "production" as a parameter isn't used somewhere in the transpiling process.

Comment: it's in your `npm run prod` command, it's the first thing: `NODE_ENV=production`.  Mix doesn't use it anywhere behind the scenes that I know of, it is just there to be used in your webpack compilation, so you can have different ones if you need ie. `dev` `stage` `production`.